# How to calculate number of characters per line using monospace font

Tags: javascript, css

I have div with css

```
div {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 1000px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

how can I calculate number of chacters that fit into this width?

Comment: No way, unless your font is monotype (and even in this case there is no 100% working way)

Comment: @hindmost update the question to include monospace font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in fit.js addon for xterm.js:

```
var div = $('div');
var span = $('<span/>').appendTo('div').html('&nbsp;');
var W = div.width();
var w = span[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
num_chars = Math.floor(W / w);
```

Comment: It seems to assume that non-breaking space is as wide as the widest character.  Not sure if it's true for proportional fonts.